# Visio UML Activity Diagram - equally space swimlanes?

Tags: layout, microsoft-visio-2013, uml

In a Visio 2013 UML Activity Diagram, how do I equally space swimlanes across the page?

If I attempt to select the whole diagram and use the right drag point, it only resizes the last vertical swimlane, not all columns. If I CTRL+click (select) all columns it nearly works, but doesn't correctly resize the header row:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I reconstructed a similar diagram in Visio 2013 (UML Activity Diagram). To resize equally all the swimlanes across the page you have to select with your mouse the whole Diagram, not just the swimlanes. Just click and hold with your mouse somewhere on the page and then move your mouse till you include the whole diagram. Take a look at the image below:

[image: Visio 2013 resize diagram equally]

All you have to do now is grab with your mouse one of the red areas I marked on the diagram and resize it. If you do it right, everything will be resized symmetrically and equally.

Comment: Is there a way to resize all the lanes to the same width?